# node_modules/@types/jquery"' has no exported member 'jQuery'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Angular 10 came out with a new feature that warns:

> To ensure the bundler can successfully optimize your application, avoid depending on CommonJS modules, and use ECMAScript module syntax in your entire application.

I have jquery and @types/jquery installed in my angular project and at first I imported jquery into a component with `import * as $ from 'jquery'` which threw the aforementioned error. When I inspect the code, it's actually importing from '../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index' which is the index.d.ts types file. That file has a single export `export = jQuery;` and references to the types file collection. If I write `import { jQuery } from 'jquery';` instead, I get the error:

> ../../../node_modules/@types/jquery"' has no exported member 'jQuery'

I'm still fairly new to typescript but working with nodejs has been very frustrating given that there are a dozen different ways to import something from a module. So how can I import jquery using the ECMAScript syntax? I've been playing around with the compiler settings and the "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" option so I can write `import $ from 'jquery'` without a red squiggly but compilation still throws the error:

> This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

which is very odd because I've tried setting this option in both tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.base.json even though one just extends the other.

Comment: What is the type script version that you are using?

Comment: ts version 6.14.4